Vertical coffin with fixed height?
In classical LaTeX, I can do
\begin{minipage}[t][⟨height⟩][t]{⟨width⟩}
   ...
\end{minipage}

to get a minipage with a fixed height. If I try to use vertical coffins instead, I can do
% \usepackage{xcoffin} in preamble

\SetVerticalCoffin ⟨coffin⟩ {⟨width⟩} {⟨material⟩}

But there seems to be no way of fixing the height.
I guess I could use a minipage inside a coffin, but that seems to kinda betray the purpose of the new coffin machinery.

I don't think that part of coffins (at least in the kernel) have been finalised yet. So there is no direct substitute for \parbox and minimpage when one use all the extra options.

workaround: use one coffin for the ht and then join the real content with the starred form?

or just set poles as required.

Depending on what you need, you can workaround the limitation either using two coffins (if you really need to set the total height/depth) or by simply changing the poles (if you actually just needed alignment). The code below uses the expl3 interface, but you can as soon use xcoffins if you don't mind the syntax and experimental status.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_gaussler_tmpa_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin
\vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin { .7\textwidth }
{
  \kant[1]
}
\vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_gaussler_tmpa_coffin { .7\textwidth }
{
  \skip_horizontal:n { .7\textwidth }
  \skip_vertical:n { 50mm }
}
\coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l_gaussler_tmpa_coffin { t } { l } \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin { t } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
\noindent
\fbox
{
  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_gaussler_tmpa_coffin { l } { b } { 0pt } { 0pt }
}
\coffin_set_horizontal_pole:Nnn \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin { b } { \coffin_ht:N \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin - 40mm - \coffin_dp:N \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin }
\coffin_set_horizontal_pole:Nnn \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin { B } { \coffin_ht:N \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin - 40mm }
\skip_vertical:n { 4\bigskipamount }
\par
\noindent
Anyone ~
\fbox
{
  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_gaussler_tmpb_coffin { B } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
}
~ Allegorically
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

The \fbox{}s are, of course, just for purposes of illustration:


How about something like this? Do you mean to set a horizontal coffin, perhaps?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}


\begin{document}

\NewCoffin\ExampleCoffin
\SetVerticalCoffin\ExampleCoffin{6cm}{\framebox{\rule[2cm]{2cm}{0pt}Example Coffin}}
\DisplayCoffinHandles\ExampleCoffin{blue}

\end{document}



Depending of what you need precisely, you can use \ResizeCoffin ⟨coffin⟩ {⟨width⟩} {⟨total-height⟩}, but this will distort the content.
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\NewCoffin\ExampleCoffin
\SetVerticalCoffin\ExampleCoffin{5cm}{\lipsum[1]}%
\TypesetCoffin\ExampleCoffin

\bigskip

\ResizeCoffin\ExampleCoffin{8cm}{5cm}
\TypesetCoffin\ExampleCoffin

\end{document}


